# Textview causing java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView

Tags: android, textview

I have three textviews and applied clickevent on them, but when i click on any of them the they cause Forceclose error in application. i have also tried changing ids textviews and then clean project and ran the project still that error is not removed.

My XML code is

for one textview

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LL_fb" 
        android:layout_width="180px"
        android:layout_height="27px"
        android:layout_above="@+id/txt_msg_regs"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/LL_signup"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:background="@drawable/facebook" >        
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/btn_txt_fb"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Connect with facebook"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

for second textview

```
<LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/LL_signup"
        android:layout_width="180px"
        android:layout_height="29px"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/LL_login"
        android:background="@drawable/lmyic_signup">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/btn_txt_sinup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="signup with email"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

for third one

```
 <LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/LL_login"
            android:layout_width="180px"
                android:layout_height="29px"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="69dp"
                android:background="@drawable/lmyic_login">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btn_txt_login"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Log in"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" 
            android:clickable="true"/> 
        </LinearLayout>
```

this is my android code. This class name in intent are also correct and i verified them.

```
TextView img_login;
img_login = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.btn_txt_login);
 img_login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if(v.getId() == img_login.getId())
                {
                Intent i_lin = new Intent(LockmeifyoucanActivity.this,lmiyc_login.class);
                startActivity(i_lin);
                }                   
            }
        });
```

Please Tell me what is wrong with this. If logcat is needed then ask me for it....

Comment: where is btn_txt_login ? Please post the XMl having  btn_txt_login.

Comment: @SamirMangroliya hello, i edited my question it is btn_txt_login in my xml code by mistake it was written like that....

Comment: post your logcat i'm sure you have some issue in lmiyc_login.class activity

Comment: you have try if(v.getId()==(R.id.btn_txt_login)) instead of v.getId() == img_login.getId()

Comment: @SamirMangroliya logcat is http://pastebin.com/WyLtTxCP

Comment: can you post line 46 of lmiyc_login.java:46 here

Comment: post com.RealAndroidApp.lmiyc_login.onCreate(lmiyc_login.java:46)

Comment: will be good if line from 42 -48

Comment: these are lines from 42-48
                      setContentView(R.layout.lmyic_login_page);       txtBack = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ImgViewTxtBack);
txtBack.setTypeface(null,Typeface.BOLD);
iv_login = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.Txtlogin);
iv_login.setOnClickListener(this);
iv_sign_up = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.TxtSignup);

Comment: pls bare with code it cant be editesd by me...

Comment: ok i will adit it can you post xml of lmyic_login_page

Comment: I think problem is with iv_login = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.Txtlogin);

Comment: because this is 46 line and it should be textview and you are castin it in Imageview

Comment: I am not sure as I am not able to see the "R.id.Txtlogin" in the complete XML provided by you.

Answer (score 1):

Please post the complete XMl so that we can view the btn_txt_login in that.

It looks it is button because "findViewById(R.id.btn_txt_login);" would return null if this "btn_txt_login" id is not in xml.

Comment: btn_txt_login should be button on UI and txt_login is textview as we can see. I think due to same almost same name you would have done this.

Comment: iff query has been resolved please vote/accept any answer found close to your answer to finish this story and make stack Clear for all....

Answer (score 1):

you have some problem with textview in lmiyc_login activity.in lmiyc_login corrent line number 46 which maybe:

```
TextView txtview;
txtview = (TextView)yourlayout.findViewById(R.id.txtviewid);
```

Comment: this lines of code are of my another page when i click on login btn on home page then this screen(lmiyc_login) should be open and it also has one login btn same as it is in home screen.

Comment: if you give a pastbin link for lmyic_login_page xml then your problem will solve in sort time

Comment: @all The problem is solved. The problem was in another page. redeclared all imageview as textview in lmiyc_login page.

Answer (score 0):

```
findViewById(R.id.btn_txt_login);
```

Is this really a TextView or do you have a Button in your layout as well? I think you're trying to cast a Button to a TextView

Answer (score 0):

Wrong resource ID...

```
img_login = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.btn_txt_login);
```

according to your XML should be

```
img_login = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_login);
```

etc..

Answer (score 0):

change ur code with this

```
TextView img_login;
 img_login = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_login);
   img_login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if(v.getId().equals(img_login.getId()))
            {
            Intent i_lin = new Intent(LockmeifyoucanActivity.this,lmiyc_login.class);
            startActivity(i_lin);
            }                   
        }
    });
```

Comment: hahahaha u wrote btn_txt_login n i wrote this R.id.txt_login           and  u wrote this v.getId() == img_login.getId() nd i wrote this v.getId().equals(img_login.getId()) nd u say its already  therr great :)

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this error quickly, set one break point at line:

```
View view = findViewById(R.id.btn_txt_login);
```

Then, see on locals tab which component is, looking at `gen/R.java.`

Answer (score 0):

these are lines from 42-48

```
 setContentView(R.layout.lmyic_login_page);                 
  txtBack = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ImgViewTxtBack);          txtBack.setTypeface(null,Typeface.BOLD);
   iv_login = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.Txtlogin);
   iv_login.setOnClickListener(this);
   iv_sign_up = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.TxtSignup);
```

I think problem is with iv_login = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.Txtlogin); – Dheeresh Singh 1 min ago edit 
because this is 46 line and it should be textview and you are castin it in Imageview – Dheeresh Singh just now edit

Answer (score 0):

if you have duplicate resource Id, that will throw ClasscastException. So make sure you don't have duplicate element id throughout the whole project.